# `ORDER BY` changes the query result even if column being sorted is not in `SELECT` statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I was working through some Oracle PL/SQL videos and I arrived at a part where a discussed query did not quite make sense to me. Particularly, how the result of the `ORDER BY` clause play into the resulting query.

Looking at this tables structure:

#### Category

- category_id (PK)
- parent_id
- name

#### Show

- show_id (PK)
- category_id (FK)
- act_id (FK)
- venue_id (FK)
- name
- showdate
- price_multiplier

And a 0 to 1 or many relationship between the Category and Show tables (so that for any category there may be 0 or more records in the Show table).

How does the `ORDER BY` clause modify what is achieved by the `GROUP BY` clause if the `COUNT (DISTINCT s.show_id)` is not a listed column/field within the SELECT statement

#### Query:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT s.category_ID) "First Categories"
FROM category c, show s
WHERE c.category_id = s.category_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY COUNT (DISTINCT s.show_id);
```

(This is in response to the down-vote: I would like to address this in that I have searched for the answer on the boards prior to posting extensively, as well as outside. I felt that this example covers a good amount of basic and important concepts between GROUP BY, SELECT and ORDER BY clauses and might be helpful for someone else who is just learning, as it is a unique enough example, but basic enough to grasp and apply down the road.)

Thank you graciously!!

Comment: Count is an aggregate as well. As such it's not needed in the group by, but it can still be calculated; and there fore used to sort.  Add the `count(Distinct s.show_ID)` to the select and you'll see it in action easier.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, it should have been an obvious enough item to try and add the `count(Distinct s.show_ID)` to the SELECT. In my defense, I am oftentimes trying to do things in my head when they 'seem' simple. This instructor has made plenty other mistakes during earlier videos, so my initial hunch was it was a mistype. I very much appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of `COUNT (DISTINCT s.show_id)` is still applied to each group of `c.name`, and the resulting rows are sorted according to it - it just isn't displayed in the final result set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. 

I am guessing then it would be safe enough to assume that the result would be the same in the scenario where 'ORDER BY` is put on `COUNT (DISTINCT s.category_id)`:

SELECT c.name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT s.category_ID) "First Categories"
FROM category c, show s
WHERE c.category_id = s.category_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY COUNT (DISTINCT s.category_id);


Is this correct?

(So sorry for the formatting, the comment fields do not allow the formatting freedom of the actual posts.)

Comment: @YekatjarinaAljaksandraynaShu not quite sure what you're asking - the **reasoning**, as detailed in my answer, would be similar, but in this query, the expression ordered by appears in the select list too, so the ordering would be much more obvious.

Comment: @YekatjarinaAljaksandraynaShu Actually I don't think so.  Distinct is important here especially since you have a one to many join.  `count(Distinct s.category_ID)` could be  very different than `count(Distinct s.show_ID)`  distinct categories for a show

Comment: @Mureinik: I understand that the ordering would be much more obvious if the column within the GROUP BY is in the SELECT statement also, but what I intended to say (which I suspect now is wrong) is that because there will always be only 1 distinct category_id and also only 1 distinct order_id (if as in original example/query) it would not matter visually what we would see resulting on screen between these two. In effect, it might be, since it would depend on which show_id appears first in the table. Yes?

Comment: In addition, I definitely wish to add that I intend on verifying the outcomes by running these in my DB after all (once I set it up). Thank you everyone for your insight and explanations. This has been rather helpful.

Comment: @YekatjarinaAljaksandraynaShu "which show_id appears first in the table" is completely arbitrary. The database only guarantees the order explicitly defined by the `order by` clause - anything else may change if you create/rebuild an index, import/export your table, defrag your underlying disk, or even upgrade the oracle software.